# Entity Framework - Update listas aninhadas

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lista-encadeada

Tenho o seguinte esquema no meu BD MySql:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Models tem uma lista de standard_images e cada standard_images tem uma lista standard_regions.
Obrigatoriamente preciso usar o  Entity Framework 5.0.0. 
Tenho um modelo com 3 standard_images e cada uma delas tem 4 standard_regions. 
Preciso fazer um update nesse modelo onde irei remover a standard_region 2 e 3  da standard_image 2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para fazer o update, estou indo até o BD, buscando o Id do modelo que desejo alterar, e através de um foreach vou varrendo o modelo do BD e atualizando com os dados vindos da interface gráfica.

Mas como fazer esse update nesse modelo quando preciso remover uma stdRegion, ou uma StdImg, ou seja, quando existe a divergência entre as listas que existem originalmente no BD e os novos dados que o usuário deseja alterar, seja adicionando ou removendo componentes de ambas as listas ?

O código para excluir uma standard_region é esse:

```
public void AlterarModelo(Modelo modAlterado)
{
    //Busca no BD o modelo a ser alterado
    models modBanco = db.models.Find(modAlterado.id);

    //apaga do banco caso não exista na lista passada via interface
    foreach(var image in modBanco.standard_images)
    {
        List<standard_regions> lista = new List<standard_regions>();

        foreach (var regiao in image.standard_regions)
        {
            foreach (var a in modAlterado.lstImagemPadrao)
            {
                if (a.lstRegiaoInteressePadrao.Count(x => x.id == regiao.id) == 0)
                {
                    var regTemp = db.standard_regions.Find(regiao.id);

                    lista.Add(regTemp);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var reg in lista)
        {
            image.standard_regions.Remove(reg);
        }
    }


    //adiciona caso não esteja no banco
    foreach (var imgAlterado in modAlterado.lstImagemPadrao)
    {
        foreach (var imgBanco in modBanco.standard_images)
        {
            foreach (var regAlterado in imgAlterado.lstRegiaoInteressePadrao)
            {
                if (regAlterado.id == 0)
                {
                    var regTemp = db.standard_regions.Find(regAlterado.id);

                    standard_regions sr = new standard_regions
                    {
                        coordinate = regAlterado.coordinate,
                        description = regAlterado.descricao,
                        standard_images_id = imgBanco.id
                    };
                    imgBanco.standard_regions.Add(sr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    modBanco.date = modAlterado.data;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

As classes Modelo, ImagemPadrao e RegiaoInteressePadrao definem os objetos de transferência onde trago os dados alterados pelo usuário na interface gráfica:

```
public class Modelo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nomeModelo { get; set; }
    public string statusModelo { get; set; }
    public DateTime data { get; set; }
    public Usuario usuario { get; set; }
    public bool foiInspecionado { get; set; }

    public ImagemPadraoColecao lstImagemPadrao { get; set; }

    public Modelo()
    {
        lstImagemPadrao = new ImagemPadraoColecao();
        usuario = new Usuario();
    }
}

public class ImagemPadrao
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nomeImagemPadrao { get; set; }
    public string caminhoImagemPadrao { get; set; }
    public Modelo modelo { get; set; }

    public RegiaoInteressePadraoColecao lstRegiaoInteressePadrao { get; set; }

    public ImagemPadrao()
    {
        lstRegiaoInteressePadrao = new RegiaoInteressePadraoColecao();
    }
}

public class RegiaoInteressePadrao
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public string coordinate { get; set; }
    public int imagemPadraoId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Para melhorar o entendimento, seria um update com uma exclusão (ou adição) de algum item de alguma das duas listas.

Comment: Tem tantas formas e tantos cenários, porque, tudo é em relação a  interface gráfica que manipula os dados e dependendo pode ser exclusões diretas visto que cada model (entidade) tem sua `primary key`.

Comment: Sua montagem dos modelos é muito peculiar. Ainda não entendi onde estão as declarações de `standard_images` e `standard_regions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com as dicas que os colegas Cigano Morrison Mendez e Rogério Amaral (ramaral) me passaram, cheguei a uma solução que atendeu o que eu estava precisando.

O meu modelo no BD realmente precisei buscar dessa maneira, como o Cigano me orientou:

```
models modBanco = db.models.Include("standard_images.standard_regions").SingleOrDefault(m => m.id == modAlteradoUi.id);
```

Dessa forma eu consegui buscar o meu modelo lá no BD para alterá-lo com os dados vindos da UI.

O colega Rogério Amaral (ramaral) mostrou sua abordagem para atualizar entidades compostas e estudando esse tipo de abordagem que não conhecia, ajustei meu código para atualizar corretamente a lista de imagens e suas sublistas de ROIS (regiões de interesse). 
O maior trabalho foi a execução da lógica para atualizar o modelo do BD com os dados vindos da Ui. Abaixo segue o código que atualiza o modelo:

```
public void AlterarModelo(Modelo modAlteradoUi)
        {
            models modBanco = db.models.Include("standard_images.standard_regions").SingleOrDefault(m => m.id == modAlteradoUi.id);
            modBanco.name = modAlteradoUi.nomeModelo;
            modBanco.users_id = modAlteradoUi.usuario.id;
            modBanco.status = modAlteradoUi.statusModelo;
            modBanco.date = modAlteradoUi.data;

            //Adiciona imagens novas, vindas da UI, com suas novas ROIS
            foreach (var imagemDaUi in modAlteradoUi.lstImagemPadrao)
            {
                if (imagemDaUi.id == 0)//Se for uma imagem nova
                {
                    //Cria essa imagem para adicionar no modelo do bd
                    standard_images siTmp = new standard_images();
                    siTmp.id = 0;
                    siTmp.name = imagemDaUi.nomeImagemPadrao;
                    siTmp.models_id = modBanco.id;
                    siTmp.path = imagemDaUi.caminhoImagemPadrao;

                    //Cria lista de Roi dessa imagem
                    List<standard_regions> lstRoitmp = new List<standard_regions>();

                    siTmp.standard_regions = lstRoitmp; //Add a lista de Roi na Nova Imagem

                    if (imagemDaUi.lstRegiaoInteressePadrao != null)//Adiciona ROI se existir na imagem da UI
                    {
                        foreach (var roiTmp in imagemDaUi.lstRegiaoInteressePadrao)
                        {
                            standard_regions stdRoiTmp = new standard_regions();
                            stdRoiTmp.id = 0;
                            stdRoiTmp.coordinate = roiTmp.coordinate;
                            stdRoiTmp.description = roiTmp.descricao;

                            lstRoitmp.Add(stdRoiTmp);
                        } 
                    }

                    modBanco.standard_images.Add(siTmp);//Add a nova imagem com suas ROIS no modelo
                }
                else    //Se a imagem já existir no BD tenho que alterar 
                {       //as Rois e adicionar as Rois novas para essa imagem já existente
                    foreach (var roiDaUi in imagemDaUi.lstRegiaoInteressePadrao)
                    {
                        if (roiDaUi.id == 0)
                        {
                            standard_regions novoRoiDaUi = new standard_regions
                            {
                                coordinate = roiDaUi.coordinate,
                                description = roiDaUi.descricao,
                                standard_images_id = imagemDaUi.id
                            };

                            foreach (var imgBanco in modBanco.standard_images.ToList())
                            {
                                if (imgBanco.id == imagemDaUi.id)
                                {
                                    //Se estou atribuindo um id da imagemDaUi em uma imgBanco,
                                    //essa imagem do banco existe não está sendo removida do
                                    //BD. Então preciso mudar o status dela para modified e adicionar
                                    //a nova roi.
                                    db.Entry(imgBanco).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                                    imgBanco.standard_regions.Add(novoRoiDaUi);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (var imgBanco in modBanco.standard_images.ToList())
                            {
                                if (imgBanco.id == imagemDaUi.id)
                                {
                                    db.Entry(imgBanco).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

                                    foreach (var roiBd in imgBanco.standard_regions)
                                    {
                                        if (roiDaUi.id == roiBd.id)
                                        {
                                            roiBd.coordinate = roiDaUi.coordinate;
                                            roiBd.description = roiDaUi.descricao;
                                            roiBd.standard_images_id = roiDaUi.imagemPadraoId;
                                            db.Entry(roiBd).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            db.models.Attach(modBanco);

            foreach (var imagem in modBanco.standard_images.ToList())
            {
                RemoveDeletedRoi(imagem.standard_regions);              
            }

            RemoveDeletedImg(modBanco.standard_images);

            db.Entry(modBanco).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Quando existem dados no modelo do BD que não existem na UI, preciso excluí-los. Para isso utilizei dos status que o EntityFramework retorna. Todas as entidades que retornam do BD, possuem o status `Unchanged`. Quando adiciono algo ao modelo, mudo seu status para `Added` , quando atualizo uso o status `Modified`, e nos que não faço nada possuem o status `Unchanged`. Eles existem no meu modelo e não na UI, sendo assim, preciso exclui-los do meu modelo. Para isso fiz os dois métodos abaixo para me auxiliarem.

```
private void RemoveDeletedImg(ICollection<standard_images> LstStdImagesBd)
        {
            var deletedImg = (from img in LstStdImagesBd where db.Entry(img).State == System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged select img).ToList();

            foreach (var img in deletedImg)
            {
                db.Entry(img).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
            }
        }

        private void RemoveDeletedRoi(ICollection<standard_regions> LstStdRoisBd)
        {
            var deletedRoi = (from roi in LstStdRoisBd where db.Entry(roi).State == System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged select roi).ToList();

            foreach (var roi in deletedRoi)
            {
                db.Entry(roi).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
            }
        }
```

Outra coisa que muito me ajudou, foi uma matéria que achei no site do Macoratti:

http://www.macoratti.net/11/11/ef4_cve1.htm

Lá existem explicações sobre essa parte de Estados do EntityFramework...

Comment: O código ainda pode ser minimizado. De qualquer forma, acho que já está bom. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, certifique-se que `Image` referencie `Region` com `cascadeDelete` habilitado. Este é um exemplo de `Migration`:

```
CreateTable(
        "dbo.Images",
        c => new
            {
                /* Coloque a declaração das colunas aqui */
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.ImageId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Regions", t => t.RegionId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.ImageId);
```

Você pode habilitar o mesmo mecanismo para `Model`, que referencia `Image` com `cascadeDelete` habilitado:

```
CreateTable(
        "dbo.Models",
        c => new
            {
                /* Coloque a declaração das colunas aqui */
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.ModelId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Images", t => t.ImageId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.ModelId);
```

Assim, basta excluir uma `Image` para que suas respectivas `Regions` sejam atualizadas.

Já para o caso da atualização, creio que você terá que continuar percorrendo elemento a elemento para atualizar. Não há caminho fácil.

---

Este código:

```
models modBanco = db.models.Find(modAlterado.id);
```

Não é bom, visto que você carrega apenas o registro do `Model`, e não suas entidades dependentes. O que está acontecendo aqui:

```
var regTemp = db.standard_regions.Find(regiao.id);
```

É que você está realizando uma carga destacada do contexto. O Entity Framework não admite que estes registros de `Region` são os registros originais em tabela, portanto, quando você apaga uma `Region`:

```
image.standard_regions.Remove(reg);
```

Ao salvar as mudanças no contexto, as `Regions` são apagadas corretamente. Só que isso aqui:

```
foreach (var imgAlterado in modAlterado.lstImagemPadrao)
{ ... }
```

Pode fazer as `Regions` serem reinseridas como novos registros. Afinal, o `SaveChanges()` fica no final do método.

### Qual a maneira correta?

Altere seu código para o seguinte:

```
//Busca no BD o modelo a ser alterado
models modBanco = db.models.Include(m => m.standard_images.standard_regions).SingleOrDefault(m => m.id == modAlterado.id);

//apaga do banco caso não exista na lista passada via interface
foreach(var image in modBanco.standard_images)
{
    foreach (var regiao in image.standard_regions)
    {
        foreach (var a in modAlterado.lstImagemPadrao)
        {
            if (a.lstRegiaoInteressePadrao.Count(x => x.id == regiao.id) == 0)
            {
                db.standard_regions.Remove(regiao);
            }
        }
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Cigano, o bd MySql não estava configurado para cascade. Fiz a configuração e funcionou. Porém agora quando executo a exclusão de uma StdRegion, na verdade o registro não é excluido, apenas é colocado null na tabela standard_regions na coluna standard_images_id.                            id='145', description='520-3', coordinate= '1660;2070;-0,6174323;190;135', standard_images_id= 'null'. O registro não deveria ser excluido por completo?

Comment: Muito esquisito. Não aplicou o `cascade` direito. Você pode atualizar sua pergunta com o código que está sendo usado para excluir a `Region`?

Comment: @Emerson Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Ok entendi, vou atualizar e te aviso o resultado. Eu acreditava que fazendo isso `models modBanco = db.models.Find(modAlterado.id);` o Entity já iria buscar também os relacionamentos. No meu entendimento, eu preciso explicitar o nível de granularidade que ele deve buscar no BD. Está correto o que estou pensando?

Comment: Exatamente. O `Find` é a operação mais barata porque traz apenas o primeiro nível de dados. `SingleOrDefault()` com os `Include`s explícitos garante a pesquisa até o terceiro nível, que é seu caso.

Answer (score 3):

Esta é a abordagem que utilizo quando quero actualizar entidades composta:

Defino uma interface `IObjectWithState`que todas as classes do meu modelo implementam:

```
public interface IObjectWithState
{
    ObjectState State { get; set; }
}
public enum ObjectState
{
    Unchanged,
    Added,
    Modified,
    Deleted
}
```

Defino uma classe de ajuda para converter `ObjectState`em `EntityState`:

```
public static class StateHelpers
{
    public static EntityState ConvertState(ObjectState objectState)
    {
        switch (objectState)
        {
            case ObjectState.Added:
                return EntityState.Added;
            case ObjectState.Modified:
                return EntityState.Modified;
            case ObjectState.Deleted:
                return EntityState.Deleted;
            default:
                return EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
    }
}
```

No meu ***Repository*** tenho um método que trata das entidades compostas:

```
public class EFEntityRepository<TEntity> :
    where TEntity : class, IObjectWithState
{
    public DbContext Context { get; set; }

    ------------------
    -------------------
    ------------------- 

    public void UpdateEntityGraph(params TEntity[] entities)
    {
        IDbSet<TEntity> set = Context.Set<TEntity>();
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            switch (entity.State)
            {
                case ObjectState.Deleted:
                    set.Attach(entity);
                    set.Remove(entity);
                    break;
                case ObjectState.Added:
                    set.Add(entity);
                    break;
                case ObjectState.Modified:
                case ObjectState.Unchanged:
                    set.Add(entity);
                    foreach (var entry in Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IObjectWithState>())
                    {
                        IObjectWithState objectState = entry.Entity;
                        entry.State = StateHelpers.ConvertState(objectState.State);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Uma ou mais entidades estão num estado inválido");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Antes de utilizar o método só necessito de indicar em cada entidade da entidade composta o seu estado: `Added`, `Modified` ou `Deleted`.

O método, como aceita `params TEntity[]`, pode ser usado para tratar várias entidades ao mesmo tempo.

Baseado em alguns artigos que li, nomeadamente de Julie Lerman.